# ngChange fires before value makes it out of isolate scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-change, isolate-scope

```
//main controller
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope){
    $scope.loadResults = function (){
        console.log($scope.searchFilter);
    };
});

// directive
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('customSearch', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            searchModel: '=ngModel',
            searchChange: '&ngChange',
        },
        require: 'ngModel',
        template: '<input type="text" ng-model="searchModel" ng-change="searchChange()"/>',
        restrict: 'E'
    };
});

// html
<custom-search ng-model="searchFilter" ng-change="loadResults()"></custom-search>
```

Here is a simplified directive to illustrate. When I type into the input, I expect the `console.log` in `loadResults` to log out exactly what I have already typed. It actually logs one character behind because `loadResults` is running just before the `searchFilter` var in the main controller is receiving the new value from the directive. Logging inside the directive however, everything works as expected. Why is this happening?

**My Solution**

After getting an understanding of what was happening with ngChange in my simple example, I realized my actual problem was complicated a bit more by the fact that the ngModel I am actually passing in is an object, whose properties i am changing, and also that I am using form validation with this directive as one of the inputs. I found that using $timeout and $eval inside the directive solved all of my problems:

```
//main controller
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope){
    $scope.loadResults = function (){
        console.log($scope.searchFilter);
    };
});

// directive
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('customSearch', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        scope: {
            searchModel: '=ngModel'
        },
        require: 'ngModel',
        template: '<input type="text" ng-model="searchModel.subProp" ng-change="valueChange()"/>',
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModel)
        {
            $scope.valueChange = function()
            {
                $timeout(function()
                {
                    if ($attrs.ngChange) $scope.$parent.$eval($attrs.ngChange);
                }, 0);
            };
        }
    };
});

// html
<custom-search ng-model="searchFilter" ng-change="loadResults()"></custom-search>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You answered your own question in the title! `'='` is watched while `'&'` is not

- Somewhere outside angular:

  input view value changes
- next digest cycle:

  `ng-model` value changes and fires `ng-change()`

  ng-change adds a $viewChangeListener and is called this same cycle. 
  See:
  [ngModel.js#L714](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.0/src/ng/directive/ngModel.js#L714%20ngModel.js#L714) and [ngChange.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.0/src/ng/directive/ngChange.js) implementation.

  At that time `$scope.searchFilter` hasn't been updated. Console.log's old value
- next digest cycle:
  `searchFilter` is updated by data binding.

UPDATE: Only as a POC that you need 1 extra cycle for the value to propagate you can do the following. See the other anwser (@NewDev for a cleaner approach).

```
.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout){
    $scope.loadResults = function (){
        $timeout(function(){
           console.log($scope.searchFilter);
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: Good answer, I was debugging Angular for the last hour to see what's up. Can you explain why it takes an additional digest cycle for the directive to update the parent scope? Is it because the digest starts from `$rootScope` and propagates down? If there was a 3rd `ng-change` along the way, would it take more digest cycles for the value to reach the controller?

Comment: The scope is isolated, directive doesn't modify parent's scope directly. They way to keep `=` vars synchronized is by using the famous angular 'data binding'.. which is basically a `$watch`. Each digest cycle angular will do the dirty check and when it detects a change, copies the value 'manually'. So, when the directive variable changes, it needs a $digest be copied to the 'parent' (while the & is a direct access)

Comment: To nitpick, `input` *triggers* the digest loop (it doesn't "happen" during a digest), and in its first iteration `searchModel` is set, and `searchChange()` (which results in `loadResults()`) is triggered... Then, in the 2nd iteration, `searchFilter` is set... But this workaround is very hacky.

Comment: you are right about first cycle not being in a cycle! ( was thinking about ngModel $viewValue.. but ngModel is not that simple) I'll edit. About being hacky, it's just what the question was... "what's going on?"

Comment: @AlejandroCotroneo, yeah, I got it... Wording probably could have been better to say that this is POC, so as not to suggest that this is, in fact, a valid workaround.

Comment: I used $timeout inside the directive, and it seems to have the added benefit of allowing outer validation to complete before firing, which I also found necessary for my situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

The reason for the behavior, as rightly pointed out in another answer, is because the two-way binding hasn't had a chance to change the outer `searchFilter` by the time `searchChange()`, and consequently, `loadResults()` was invoked.

The solution, however, is very hacky for two reasons.

One, the caller (the user of the directive), should not need to know about these workarounds with `$timeout`. If nothing else, the `$timeout` should have been done in the directive rather than in the View controller.

And two - a mistake also made by the OP - is that using `ng-model` comes with other "expectations" by users of such directives. Having `ng-model` means that other directives, like validators, parsers, formatters and view-change-listeners (like `ng-change`) could be used alongside it. To support it properly, one needs to `require: "ngModel"`, rather than bind to its expression via `scope: {}`. Otherwise, things would not work as expected.

Here's how it's done - for another example, see [the official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#custom-control-example) for creating a custom input control.

```
scope: true, // could also be {}, but I would avoid scope: false here
template: '<input ng-model="innerModel" ng-change="onChange()">',
require: "ngModel",
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls){
  var ngModel = ctrls; // ngModelController

  // from model -> view
  ngModel.$render = function(){
    scope.innerModel = ngModel.$viewValue;
  }

  // from view -> model
  scope.onChange = function(){
    ngModel.$setViewValue(scope.innerModel);
  }
}
```

Then, `ng-change` just automatically works, and so do other directives that support `ngModel`, like `ng-required`.

Comment: I realized I left some key info out of my example. My outer ngModel is actually an object, and I'm trying to use multiple inputs inside the directive to change properties of that object, but still treat the directive like a single input.

Comment: @RobbyAllsopp, ok, that's fine with the approach I gave you. But your approach with `$timeout` and binding directly to `ngModel` is wrong and could produce unexpected results. For example, suppose you wanted to use `ng-model-options` with `debounce` on your directive - it would not have any effect. Like I said, to use `ng-model` means that you support the `ngModelController` "framework".

Comment: good point it would mess up some other things with ngModel. I can't see a way around the `$timeout` though if i still want validation to work, but i could probably swap out the `$eval` for `ngModel.$setViewValue(angular.copy($scope.searchModel))`. I may switch to that, although i'm not excited about having to copy the whole object every time anything changes

Comment: @RobbyAllsopp, I'm not sure what you mean by validation. Validation is supported via `ngModel`. In fact, I'm fairly certain, that with your `$timeout` approach it wouldn't work, since a change directly via isolate scope binding bypasses parses and validators. And, you need to create a new object for the "change" to register.

Comment: Is something changed in Angular?  This isn't working for me.  Changes to the ngModel would change your textbox, but changes to the textbox don't update the ngModel.  Though, the onChange is definitely being called.  Also, once the textbox value differs from the ngModel (via manual input), it no longer even updates when the ngModel is changed elsewhere.  Lastly, wouldn't it be `require: '^ngModel'`? Can you do a Plunker?

Comment: This should be accepted answer