# AngularJS: bind to parent ngChange

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I'm trying to create a directive to replace a bunch of identical inputs

```
(function () {
  angular
    .module('myModule')
    .directive('pageSearchInput', PageSearchInputDirective);

  function PageSearchInputDirective() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      require: 'ngModel',
      scope: {
        ngModel: '=',
        ngChange: '&'
      },
      replace: true,
      template:
        `<input type="text" ng-model-options="{debounce: 1000}" ng-model="ngModel" ng-change="ngChange()">`
    };
  }
}());
```

And here is usage example:

```
<page-search-input ng-model="keyword" ng-change="someFunction()"></page-search-input>
```

And in my controller

```
$scope.keyword = '';
$scope.someFunction = function() {
    console.log($scope.keyword);
};
```

So my problem is that `$scope.keyword` is one step behind.
When I type the following

`a
ab
abc`

Console log gives me

`''
a
ab`

And if I simply put

`<input type="text" ng-model-options="{debounce: 1000}" ng-model="keyword" ng-change="someFunction()">`

into my template everything works perfect.

Any ideas, please?

Comment: Answer to your question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33178205/ngchange-fires-before-value-makes-it-out-of-isolate-scope

Comment: @VitaliiChmovzh thank you very much!